# how to go bottom of a website like back to top using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I include coding on my blog for **Back to top** using HTML, CSS & JavaScript combination. Now I want to include which may work as opposition of **Back to top** that means **Go to Bottom**. For back to top I include code like this:
**HTML**

```
<div id="back-top">
<a href="#top">
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6KDdSchHT18/Uvxj4CJipXI/AAAAAAAAE4k/wyk-sSq5gbc/s1600/Back-to-top.png"/><br/>Top</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#back-top a{text-decoration: none;}
#back-top {
color: #ff0000;
position: fixed;
bottom: 25px;
left: 125px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function (){ 
$(window).scroll(function (){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){
$('#back-top').fadeIn();
} 
else{
$('#back-top').fadeOut();
}
});
```

How can alternate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To smoothly scroll to the body's end you can use this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zr4Sp/)

```
$(function (){ 
    var bodyHeight = $('body').height();

    $('#back-bottom a').on('click', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: bodyHeight}, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working with **jquery version 1.9.1** and I include it to **my blog http://tutxt.blogspot.com**

Answer (score 1):

A very simple trick is to include at the very bottom of your page a `div` like so:

```
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Then link to it with

```
<a href="#bottom">Go To Bottom</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="here">&nbsp;</span>

<div id="back-bottom">
<a href="#here">
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6KDdSchHT18/Uvxj4CJipXI/AAAAAAAAE4k/wyk-sSq5gbc/s1600/Back-to-top.png"/><br/>Bottom</a></div>
```

Try the above!